# MySQL (Clear DB) on Azure in Open offer

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure

I have purchased an Azure subscription through a reseller (so the offer is of the Azure in Open type) on which I would like to host a wordpress-based webpage (amongst other services). In order to do that I need to create a MySQL database and I would like to use a shared Clear DB for it. However, neither ClearDB nor MySQL database is available for me to be created on the subscription (these resources simply do not appear in the list). There is a credit card linked to the subscription already.

The only option Azure gives me is to create a VM with MySQL pre-installed, however the price for that is (obviously) way higher. I've checked the FAQ site for Clear DB on Azure (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/store-cleardb-faq), but if I'm not wrong I already have the requirements fulfilled.

What settings do I have to change in order to be able to create a Clear DB instance on the subscription? Am I missing something?

Comment: why don't you raise a ticket to azure support ? Here are the steps to do the same. `Help + Support` --> `New Support Request`

Comment: I was about to do that, but I wasn't sure if I just missed something obvious...

Comment: No, you should ask them and the service is pretty fast. Make sure you make you  case level priority to at least 'B' level. So, They can contact you ASAP.